# Is Math.Log implemented in a way to avoid loss of precision for log(1 + x)?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, precision, logarithm

I'm translating some C# code to C++, which contains uses of `Math.Log(1 + x)`, where x can be a very small value close to zero. I came across the recommendation (in C++) to use `std::log1p` for when dealing with `log(1 + x)`, where `x` is close to zero, i.e. [to avoid loss of precision](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/20629/when-should-log1p-and-expm1-be-used).

Is the C#/.NET `Math.Log` method implemented in a way that similarly avoids loss of precision? I could not find a similar `Math.Log1p()` function referenced to in the .NET API reference.

Comment: try it yourself?

Comment: Does MSDN have anything to say on the matter?

Comment: @Plutonix - I tried a search for log1p but couldn't find anything. Nothing similar appears in the sidebar on the Math.Log entry: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.log(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Steve I don't have a way of testing C#/.NET code right now, I'm on a linux machine writing C++ (yes I guess I could install Mono etc.)

Comment: Looks to me like the loss of precision is not inside the function, but when preparing the input parameter.

Comment: just install Mono and test it out. When in doubt check the documentation, if it doesn't say anything then nothing is guaranteed. It would depend on the implementation (.NET VS Mono)

Comment: That's why I'm asking - I don't have a way of testing a .NET implementation. I just wondered if anyone knew

Answer (score 3):

No, Math.Log() use the C library function log() to get its job done.  log1p() is in fact included in the CRT library that the CLR uses but it is not exposed through the framework.  You can fix that with a pinvoke declaration:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public static class Math {
    public static double Log1p(double arg) {
        if (arg < -1.0) throw new ArgumentException();
        return log1p(arg);
    }

    [DllImport("msvcr120_clr0400.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    private static extern double log1p(double arg);
}
```

If you need to target a .NET version less than 4.0 then consider to change the DllImport declaration to use "ucrtbase.dll".

Notable perhaps is that I could not get consistent perf on this code.  Targeting x64 on both C# and C on my poky laptop I got ~140 nanoseconds per call.  But saw a big difference when targeting x86, 225 vs 40.  Big difference, I don't have a good explanation for that.

Answer (score 1):

Looking into the [reference implementation](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/math.cs), `Log()` just calls an extern function `Log()` that I assume is just the logarithm function of the instruction set.

The popular library *Accord.Math* indeed has a [`log1p`](http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/M_Accord_Math_Special_Log1p.htm) function which is [pretty simple](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/csharp_log_one_plus_x/) and can be implemented through following one-liner:

```
static double log1p(double x)
    => Math.Abs(x) > 1e-4 ? Math.Log(1.0 + x) : (-0.5 * x + 1.0) * x;
```

Comment: I'm not aware of any CPU which has a `LOG` instruction.

Answer (score 1):

```
double VerySmall = .0000000000000002;
double TooSmall = .0000000000000001;
Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", Math.Log(1 + VerySmall), Math.Log(1 + TooSmall), log1p(TooSmall));

static double log1p(double x)
      => Math.Abs(x) > 1e-4 ? Math.Log(1.0 + x) : (-0.5 * x + 1.0) * x;
```

In .NET framework 4.6.1 running on Windows, the output of this code is:

```
2.22044604925031E-16 0 1E-16
```